# iOS7 Popup or Notification lasting a few seconds

Tags: ios, time, ios7, notifications, popup

Is there a standard way to display a short message to the user in an iOS application and then disappear automatically.

I have an app where a user can make changes. If he/she saves the changes I want to give feedback. But it's probably annoying if an AlertBox is displayed all the time and the user needs to klick on a button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options that you can try. What you want might be the following :

Create an UIView, where you want to give feedback. This way, you can create it exactly the way you want it.

Set it hidden by default. `yourView.alpha = 0.0f;` => required if you want to animate when it appears, if not, just use `yourView.hidden = true` and ignore all animation stuff below, just replace it by `yourView.hidden = false`.

When you need your user to see your feedback you can animate it by the following :

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeIn" context:nil]; 
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; // add the value you want 
yourView.alpha = 1.0f; 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Right after, to hide it again but later, add the following :

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = 1.0f; // how long your view will last before hiding
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeInterval target:self selector:@selector(hideView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Finally, create your hideView method, that will be called by your timer :

```
-(void) hideView {
[UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeOut" context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5]; // add the value you want 
    yourView.alpha = 0.0f; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Maybe there are better ways to do it, but i think this one will do the trick, and lets you create your view as you need it. The trick with animation will add a nice look and feel to your feedback.  Hope that helps :)

Comment: Looks like a great alternative compared to add/remove a subview. Esp if there are more than one notifications at around the same time. So here we can combine it easy with a stack.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Custom View by UIView and use the NSTimer to display it for a certain time and remove the view

Answer (score 1):

You can display a custom view with `[.... addSubview: yourView]`.

After that, u create a NSTimer, with a 1 second delay for example.
On the timer´s selector, u can do a backcount, and show for example 
on your custom view, how much remain time the view will be shown.
On the selector, make an if, and after X seconds just do

`[youtView removeFromSuperview]`;

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom view with scheduled timer to present some info and then hide it when the timer completes.

However, if you are looking for a Android-style toast that shows pop-up like information and then hides after a specific time. Then, you might consider using  [Toast Control for iOS](https://github.com/scalessec/Toast). This is one of the easiest controls (Atleast, I've come across) for implementing simple popup without having user to cancel it.

Comment: Looks like a good framework and the lizence is also very liberate